# only get the latest/newest record to show

Tags: sql, window-functions

ok, so i have a column that shows levels and a column that shows players that have stopped playing at that specific level.

now a player that played to level 5 also gets listed on level 4, 3, 2 and 1. thats exactly what i dont want.
if a player has played to level 5, i want him to be counted only on the row of level 5 and so on.

how to do that?

for example, this is what i get:

```
level  stopped_playing
101     2632
102     1206
103     970
104     920
```

this is what i want:

```
level  stopped_playing
101     1426
102     236
103     50
104     920
```

920 players reached level 104 (and thus played level 101 of course) and stopped there, 1426 played only level 101 and stopped there already.
but in the result i get the 920 that reached level 4 are also counted on the level 101 row.

how to avoid that?

Comment: Pl post your table structure

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this (adapt to your actual tables):

```
select stopped_level, count(player) from (
        select player, max(level) as stopped_level
            from whatever_your_tables_are
            group by player
    )
    group by stopped_level
```

*Note: in the future it would be helpful to list your tables and their structure.  Also, it is good to mention what brand of SQL you are using, as they all have different capabilities.*

Answer (score 0):

Rough idea considering your table structure will be

```
Select Level, count(*) 
from (select player, max(Level)  as 'Level'
from table group by player) group by Level;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned your RDBMS. Problem can be easily solved using window functions, that exists in PostgreSQL, ORACLE, DB2, SQL Server 2012, Teradata, Sybase and Vertica.

The following query is tested on PostgreSQL (also on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3c0e2/1)):

```sql
SELECT *,
       stopped_playing - lag(stopped_playing,1,0)
                             OVER (ORDER BY level DESC) wanted
  FROM tab
 ORDER BY level;
```

Comment: Window function are also available on DB2, SQL Server 2012, Teradata, Sybase and Vertica.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks, I'm certain bout ORACLE and Postgres, so I've mentioned them. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great application for window functions.  Assuming that the maximum level is the highest value, try this:

```
select maxlevel, COUNT(*) as Stopped_Playing
from (select t.*,
             MAX(level) over (partition by playerid) as maxlevel
      from t
     ) t
group by maxlevel
order by maxlevel
```